# How to select 2 columns of different id

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I want to display all columns (courses) with different titles

I have 1 table called `course`

```
|---------- id -----------|------ id_user ----|----title_course---|

|.......... 1 ............|....... 5  ........|...... title1 .....|

|.......... 2 ............|.......7  .........|...... title2 .....|

|.......... 3 ............|....... 9  ........|...... title3 .....|
```

When I'm running this code

```
<?php 
$stmt = $connect->query(" SELECT * FROM course ");

while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) 
{
?> 
     <div class="all" > <?php echo $row['title_course']; ?>  </div>
<?php } ?>
```

The problem is this always displays

`title3`

Result :

```
<div class="all" > title3  </div>
<div class="all" > title3  </div>
<div class="all" > title3  </div>
```

Comment: A column `user` would be unlikely to appear in a table `course`

Answer (score 1):

**PDOStatement::execute** — Executes a prepared statement

**PDOStatement::fetch** — Fetches the next row from a result set

**PDOStatement::fetchAll** — Returns an array containing all of the result set rows

**PDOStatement::fetchColumn** — Returns a single column from the next row of a result set

```
<?php
$stmt = $connect->prepare("SELECT * FROM course");
$stmt->execute();

/* Fetch all of the remaining rows in the result set */
print("Fetch all of the remaining rows in the result set:\n");
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();

foreach ($result as $res) {
  print_r($res);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Sinto mentioned
use fetchAll() to get all results and then loop through the results set

Answer (score 0):

not working always display last result

```
<?php 
$stmt = $connect->prepare(" SELECT * FROM course ");
$stmt->execute();
$mae = $stmt->fetchAll() ;
foreach ($mae as $row ) { ?>
  <div> print_r($row['id_user']); </div>
  <div> print_r($row['id_user']); </div>
  <div> print_r($row['id_user']); </div>
<?php } ?>
```

result

```
<div> 9 </div>
<div> 9 </div>
<div> 9 </div>
```

Comment: What you are actually trying to say?

Comment: I want to create news system (user publication), 
and I just want to display for each user their id

Comment: Is this your answer to question? 3 times displayed means there is 3 records on db. Can you check `print_r($mae);` before `foreach()` & verify output of query.